# how to get (publish) .app or pkg file for MacOS in Visual Studio in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui, mac-catalyst

I'm developing an application using .NET MAUI Xaml(earlier known as WPF) to publish cross platforms. As far as my research I couldn't find any decent solution to get .App or pkg file to distribute application that's been built.

It's not compulsory to publish on App Store. We can distribute our application on other platforms by letting users know the application package is available in the address which we tell.

I only need to get this application run on MacOS and Windows. I only have Windows machine and dont have Mac. So question is how can i get application package ready to install/run on MacOS by using Visual Studio on Windows Machine.

Comment: See doc [Publish a .NET MAUI Mac Catalyst app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/deployment/): *"Publishing a .NET MAUI Mac Catalyst app builds on top of Apple's provisioning process, which requires you to have: ... A Mac on which you can build your app."* Consider [online mac build machine](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+mac+build+machine&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS950US950&sxsrf=AB5stBj4_abHCbAcwMLn-ITbT9jMn_XB4g%3A1688240457732&ei=SYGgZMGwLLOJptQPtK2cgAI&ved=0ahUKEwiB-Zzmoe7_AhWzhIkEHbQWByAQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=online+mac+build+machine). Also requires Apple dev account.